# How can 2 different requests from the same mobile be interpreted in the server side as having 2 different IPs?

Tags: ios, node.js, express, ip

I'm running a server on Node.js that listens to requests from mobile web sites (IOS).
I'm interpreting the IP from the request using the following:

```
ipAddress = function (req) {
  var header = req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
  if (header) {
    var ips = header.split(/\s*,\s*/)
    if (ips.length > 0) {
      return ips[0]
    }
  }
  return req.ip
}
```

I've noticed that sometimes I get different IPs for different requests coming from the same mobile. But haven't figured out why.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?
I've done some research and it seemed that the best way to find the IP on a request is using the x-forwarded-for in the header - is this so?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, because they are mobile.  Devices can move between cells, move between cellular and Wi Fi or suffer momentary cellular network disconnection and reconnection.  Any of these things can cause the device to be issued a new IP address.

Additionally, many cellular network providers use network address translation (NAT) and proxies.  It may be that different requests go through different proxy or NAT devices in the provider's network.

Most Proxy servers add the x-forwarded-for header but it is not mandatory.  NAT devices will not add the header.

Comment: I've also noted that some of these IPs are coming from different countries (something around 1%). Do you think this could be due to NAT devices?

Comment: Despite what you see on "CSI" tracking an IP address to a location can be imprecise :).  It relies on information from routing tables and address allocations that aren't always accurate.